# Are the API keys on data.gov considered sensitive?

Tags: api, data.gov, ckan

To access the US data.gov public datasets, you need a [CKAN API key](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/index.html#authentication-and-api-keys).

Should I consider this sensitive information, e.g. can anyone having my API key 'misuse' it so that it causes me harm, directly or indirectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some [API limits](https://api.data.gov/docs/rate-limits/) tied to a specific API key. If a third-party used your key, their calls would effect how many calls you can make.